# Why is a city owned by an enemy but puppeted by another enemy immediately annexed after conquest?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I got a very odd behavior of a Civ5 game.

I play Attila and at some point of time Poland and Shoshone declare war. Poland has conquered one Shoshone city some time ago.

So I go and take the Poland-occupied Shoshone city and it gets automatically annexed. I don't get a pop-up to choose - raze, puppet or annex.

Another situation in the same game/war:

Riga was my ally and it got conquered by Milan (ally of Poland). By the way this creates the funny situation that Milan is a two-city City State. I go and to liberate Riga but when I take the city, it gets automatically annexed again. No pop-up to liberate or anything.

I don't have any add-ons - just the standard game with all expansion packs and fully patched (automatically via Steam).

Any idea why?

Comment: I believe that is a bug, but I am not sure if it is one that was ever fixed. I can't provide more detail because the forums that talk about that bug are now phishing sites.

Comment: @n_palum really looks like a bug. I reloaded the game and this stopped. Also all annexed cities suddenly started generating unhapyness which was ... auch :)

Comment: Often a solution in many cases, I love Civ V but the bugs were plenty... Some mods address stuff too if you wanted to explore the workshop